# Format a formula in human readable form

Tags: output-formatting, display

Is there a way to make a formula display in a human readable form? I have something like

```
Binomial[(10000000 - 1), x]*(1/2^24)^x
```

and I'd like it to display using C notation or variants thereof.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at *TraditionalForm* (and *HoldForm* in combination if you don't want evaluation)

Comment: @rasher Thanks. Is there a way to leave the output as fractions as well? `TraditionalForm` seems to evaluate the fractions.

Comment: HoldForm[Binomial[(10000000 - 1), x]*(1/2^24)^x] // TraditionalForm  does not do what you're after?

Comment: @rasher Well, not entirely. TraditionalForm evaluates (1/2^24)^x to 16777216^-x whereas HoldForm doesn't use a C notation but outputs Binomial[10000000-1, x]. I wonder if there's some kind of merge of the two? :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify what you're after. Do you want the binomial to be 9999999,x?

Comment: @rasher Sorry. I was hoping to have the binomial as either C(9999999, x) or variants of it whilst using fractions whenever relevant.

Comment: Well, so I seem to have missed your point. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understand the question. I have interpreted this is wishing to display an expression in a particular form.

```
f /: MakeBoxes[f[n_, x_, num_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox[
    RowBox[{AdjustmentBox[SuperscriptBox["", MakeBoxes[n]], 
       BoxMargins -> -0.15, BoxBaselineShift -> -1], 
      MakeBoxes[Style["C", Italic, 20], StandardForm]}], 
    MakeBoxes[x]], 
   SuperscriptBox[
    RowBox[{"(", FractionBox[1, SuperscriptBox[2, MakeBoxes[num]]], 
      ")"}], MakeBoxes[x]]}]
```

So,

```
Grid[{{f[a, b, c], Rasterize@TraditionalForm[f[a, b, c]]},
  {f[10000000 - 1, x, 24], 
   Rasterize@TraditionalForm[f[10000000 - 1, x, 24]]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it is C-like syntax you are after, `CForm` is your friend:

```
CForm[Binomial[(10000000-1),x]*(1/2^24)^x]
```

outputs

```
Binomial(9999999,x)/Power(16777216,x)
```

To better preserve the original formula you gave, you can use:

```
CForm@HoldForm[Binomial[(10000000-1),x]*(1/2^24)^x]
```

which outputs

```
Binomial(10000000 - 1,x)*Power(1/Power(2,24),x)
```

## Update

As you seemed to look for only the `Binomial`'s arguments to be evaluated, while the fractions should stay there, please try:

```
Replace[HoldForm[
 Binomial[(10000000-1),x]*(1/2^24)^x],{Times[x_, y_] :> 
  Times[HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]], Binomial->C},{3, \[Infinity]},
 Heads -> True] // ReleaseHold
```

giving the possibly desired result. Of course you can then call `CForm` again, in order to get the round brackets, but this time with only the Binomial's parameters having been simplified:

```
C(9999999,x)*Power(1*1/Power(2,24),x)
```